# Schema.org - JSON-LD - Best Practice for Services

Tags: seo, schema, json-ld

For a dentist site I'm trying to create a json-ld to help with the seo.

It has a home page with all the services.  Teeth whiting, teeth cleaning

What is the best way to list the multiple services?

Thoughts?

Comment: 1) Your example seems to be missing. 2) Note that asking for SEO advice is off-topic here. You can ask how to represent something with Schema.org, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The head of Google search Gary Illyes recently confirmed schema markup do not directly affect rankings in google search.

If your goal is impacting either Click Thru Rate or Google Map optimization then this could still be beneficial (specifically star reviews on the CTR front).

To answer your question in more detail: How can I make sure Google does not show title and meta tags that has been replaced and no longer in my source code?

If the above applies, here is the documentation it's pretty straightforward: https://schema.org/LocalBusiness